# Can not use await + Result.Error:- 'string' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' and no accessible extension method 'GetAwaiter'

Tags: asp.net-core, asynchronous, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have the following code inside my asp.net core mvc:-

```
var result = await _context.Settings.SingleOrDefaultAsync(a => a.Name.ToLower() == "noofvisits").Result.Value;
```

but i got this error:-

```
Error   CS1061  'string' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' and no accessible extension method 'GetAwaiter' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

so why i am getting this error?
Thanks

Comment: Hi @test test,just using `var result = await _context.Settings.SingleOrDefaultAsync(a => a.Name.ToLower() == "noofvisits");` It could get the value where the name equals to noofvisits.

Comment: Hi @test test,did my answer help you resolve your issue?

Answer (score 2):

You are specifying an `await` for an asynchronous call that you are subsequently blocking on the result for. By adding `.Result`, your code is now acting synchronously, returning a string and not a Task that can be awaited, which is what the `await` keyword is meant for.

The return type of `SingleOrDefaultAsync()` is a `Task<T>` where `T` is whatever data type that is supposed to return. With the `await`, you are telling your code "Hey, whenever that task finishes and gives me a result, I'm waiting for that result".

If the expected data type is already a string, you don't have to do anything, you'd get a string back by doing:

`string result  = await _context.Settings.SingleOrDefaultAsync(a => a.Name.ToLower() == "noofvisits");`

If it's a more complex POCO or something you need to grab a string from synchronously after you get the result, then you can do so after the task has finished:

```
var result  = await _context.Settings.SingleOrDefaultAsync(a => a.Name.ToLower() == "noofvisits");
string yourString = result.DoWhateverHere();
```

Comment: but if i remove the `.Result.Value` how i can get the `Value` ?

Comment: as i can not mentione something as follow `await _context.Settings.SingleOrDefaultAsync(a => a.Name.ToLower() == "noofvisits").Value`

Comment: The `SingleOrDefaultAsync()` method returns a `Task<T>` where `T` is the underlying return type. If that's already a string, you don't have to do anything; `await` is waiting for the Task to complete and giving you the result. If it is a more complex type for which you need to extract the string synchronously, then let the `await` work on the `result`, then manipulate the `result` in a following line of code (i.e. `result.DoAThing()`)

Comment: can you provide an example to your reply?

Comment: As an aside, this is a good read: https://markheath.net/post/async-antipatterns

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the single object,using:

```
var result = await _context.Settings
                           .SingleOrDefaultAsync(a => a.Name.ToLower() == "noofvisits");
```

If you want to get the single property in the object,using:

```
var result = await _context.Settings.Where(a => a.Name.ToLower() == "noofvisits")
                                    .Select(s => s.PropertyName).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```